# Laravel 500 Internal server error but CSRF tokens are set

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a new Laravel project that I started on my own. I am trying to save 3 fields to the database. I have a Posts table, where I have Title, Post body, and author as fields. When trying to save I get a `500 internal server` error. I have checked my `CSRF` tokens - they are correctly setup. I am really unsure where the problem lies.

Here is my View:

```
  <div class="row">
    <h1>Create a post</h1>
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="createTitle" id="createTitle">
    <label for="post">Post</label>
    <textarea name="createPost" rows="8" cols="80" id="createPost"></textarea>
    <label for="author">Author</label>
    <input type="text" name="createAuthor" id="createAuthor">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Post" id="submit">
  </div>
```

My Ajax:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var title = $("#createTitle").val();
      var body = $("#createPost").val();
      var author = $("#createAuthor").val();

      $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content")
        }
      });

      $.ajax({
        url:'/index/create',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          title: title,
          body: body,
          author: author
        },
        success:function(response){
          $("#response").append("div" + response + "</div>");
        },
        error: function(error){
          $("#response").append("div" + error + "</div>");
        }
      });

    });
  });
```

My route:

```
    Route::post('/index/create', 'HomeController@create');
```

My Controller:

```
public function create(Request $request){

  $post = new Post;
  $post->title = $request->input('createTitle');
  $post->post = $request->input('createPost');
  $post->author = $request->input('createAuthor');

  $post->save();

  $response = [
    'response' => 'successfully added',
    'error' => 'something went wrong'
  ];

  return response()->json($response);
}
```

Comment: You do have that csrf meta tag set?

Comment: Post the error you are getting. Check laravel logs. storage/logs/

Comment: Are you with the Debug mode turned on? If not, edit your .env file and try to save again. If the error shows up, post here the stack trace

Comment: make sure in your controller you have use Post; and use Illuminate\Http\Request; and open network tab and tell us the erorrs

Comment: Other than that: your fields are not named correctly, in your ajax you send `'title'`, in your action you use `$request->input('createTitle')`

Comment: @kerbholz thank you, I have solved this now - you were right, I should have checked the fields' names.

Comment: Glad you could solve it